# How to make custom resource offers from a Mesos slave?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Is there a way to make custom resource offers from a Mesos slave? Currently, the resource offers from the slave contain "cpus", "mem", "ports". I want to add custom resource capabilities like upload bandwidth limit, download bandwidth limit etc. There is an option of doing this via the `--resources` parameter while starting the slave. But what I am looking for is a way to achieve this via code, may be a pluggable module to Mesos, so that the person who is launching the slaves doesn't have to bother about specifying the custom resources.

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources reported by the Mesos agent (aka slave) should be specified by the `--resources` flag. If the flag is omitted, defaults are used. Note that custom resources advertised via `--resources` will not be isolated, i.e. Mesos agent will not ensure a task is using not more than allocated amount of such resource.

Why do you think a module is a nicer solution than a flag? Loading custom modules requires setting some command line flags as well.

Comment: Thank you @rukletsov. The reason i was looking to load a module to find the custom resources is because some of these resources will depend on environment/machine on which the mesos slave is being launched. For e.g. download bw limit. It would be good if it could be found programmatically rather than expect the user to know about these resources when launching a mesos slave. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: I just wanted to add an example to make this more clear. The [https://github.com/Netflix/Fenzo] [fenzo scheduler] uses "network" custom resource to specify the network bandwidth in mbps. Although this could be specified using the `--resources` flag, it would be good if it could be automatically found programmatically while launching mesos slave

Comment: It does make sense. Can't you achieve your goal in a different way? For example, launch a script, determine the resource value, put it into an env variable and use it while constructing `--resources` flag?

Comment: I guess it will have to be through a script as you suggested, given that mesos doesn't provide a way to do it by loading a custom module. Thank you for your help @rukletsov